# SQL Update statement not working - SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update

I am trying to run the below sql statement (SQL Server), however getting the error

"FROM clause in UPDATE and DELETE statements cannot contain subquery sources or joins."

```
update fp 

set fp.totalcapacity = hc.totalcapacity, 
fp.sellablecapacity = hc.sellablecapacity

from [fact].[FinalPosition] fp

join fact.[HotelCapacity] hc
on fp.hotelkey = hc.hotelkey
and fp.staydate = hc.staydate

where fp.staydate = '2016-06-18'
```

I can't seem to understand why I am getting this error. Any idea?

Comment: Is `fp` an actual table or an alias?

Comment: sorry copied the wrong query. edited now. fp is an actual table. The above query is not working

Comment: Don't reference the `fp` alias in the set statements. That's your problem. See Gordon's answer below.

Comment: You can't `SET fp.totalcapacity =`, you've already specified the target in `UPDATE fp`, which means that you should only have `SET totalcapacity =` *(without the `fp.`)*.

Comment: Still getting the same error

Answer (score 3):

I think the syntax you want is:

```
update fp 
    set totalcapacity = hc.totalcapacity, 
        sellablecapacity = hc.sellablecapacity
    from fp join
         fact.[HotelCapacity] hc
         on fp.hotelkey = hc.hotelkey and fp.staydate = hc.staydate
    where fp.staydate = '2016-06-18';
```

If you want `fp` to refer to an actual table, include that in the `from` clause and make the `fp` the alias for the table.

Comment: sorry accidentally copied the wrong query. I have adjusted the correct query now. Not working

Comment: changed it to update fp

set totalcapacity = hc.totalcapacity, 
sellablecapacity = hc.sellablecapacity

from [fact].[FinalPosition] fp

join fact.[HotelCapacity] hc
on fp.hotelkey = hc.hotelkey
and fp.staydate = hc.staydate

where fp.staydate = '2016-06-18'

Comment: @Sharingan . . . What version of SQL Server are you using?  `join`s in updates have been supported for a long time, but not forever.

Comment: SQL Server 12.0.2000.8,

Comment: @Sharingan Then you have some other code causing the error, or you're not showing what you're actually executing.  Here is a [demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/b46e2/2) of it working.  *(Also, please don't ever state **"not working"**, please be certain to show exactly what you're executing and the exact results or error messages.)*